# How to obtain the arbitrary-constant-free solution of this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the substitution $$ u := y^3 $$ changes the differential equation $$ (x + y^3) + 6xyy^{\prime} = 0 $$ into the linear equation $$ u^{\prime} + \frac{1}{2x} u = - \frac{1}{2}, $$ and the latter has a solution $$ u = c x^{-1/2} - \frac{1}{3}x,$$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant, for $x > 0$. However, the above equation also has the solution $$ u = -\frac{1}{3}x $$ for all $x$. How to obtain this solution? What is the systematic procedure?

Answer (score 3):

You have a homogeneous solution and a particular solution.

For the homogeneous solution, we have:

$$ u^{\prime} + \frac{1}{2x} u = 0$$

So, we get:

$$u_H = cx^{-1/2}$$

To find the particular solution, we have:

$$ u'+ \dfrac{1}{2x} u = - \dfrac{1}{2}$$

We choose $u_P = cx$, and upon solving for $c$ by substituting back into the ODE, we get $c = -1/3$, thus:

$$u_P = -\dfrac{1}{3}x$$

Thus the solution is:

$$u(x) = u_H + u_P = c x^{-1/2} - \frac{1}{3}x$$

Comment: How to decide which form of potential solution to try?

Comment: Believe it or not, guessing (yes, you heard that right). We have a first order system and the result is a constant, first thought, try $c x$ and it worked. This is also true for more complex problems, you look at the solution and choose arbitrary particular solutions and just try them. See the examples using [*Undetermined Coefficients*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx) Regards

Comment: Helpful! And Honest, and Helpful Again!